# How do I edit a resource configuration with kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I've created a resource with:
`kubectl create -f example.yaml`

How do I edit this resource with kubectl?  Supposedly `kubectl edit`, but I'm not sure of the resource name, and `kubectl edit example` returns an error of:

```
the server doesn't have a resource type "example"
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do a `kubectl edit -f example.yaml` to edit it directly. Nevertheless I would recommend to edit the file locally and do a `kubectl apply -f example.yaml`, so it gets updated on Kubernetes.

Also: Your command fails, because you have to specify a resource type. Example types are `pod`, `service`, `deployment` and so on. You can see all possible types with a plain `kubectl get`. The type should match the `kind` value in the YAML file and the name should match `metadata.name`.

For example the following file could be edited with `kubectl edit deployment nginx-deployment`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 2 # tells deployment to run 2 pods matching the template
  template: # create pods using pod definition in this template
    metadata:
      # unlike pod-nginx.yaml, the name is not included in the meta data as a unique name is
      # generated from the deployment name
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Comment: What resource type would it be in this case? Or does it depend on the contents of my `example.yaml`?

Comment: It depends on the content.

Comment: I added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: Just a note. Using `apply` gives me an warning of: `Warning: kubectl apply should be used on resource created by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply`.

`kubectl replace -f example.yaml` seems to achieve the above without the warning.

Comment: That seems new. We always create and change resource with `kubectl apply`. This way it works without warning.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski Quote from kubernete.io:
"Warning: Mixing kubectl apply with the imperative object configuration commands create and replace is not supported. This is because create and replace do not retain the kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration that kubectl apply uses to compute updates."
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/object-management-kubectl/declarative-config/