# Using kubectl path to update k8s manifest without modifying the file manually

Tags: kubernetes

I am following the sample azure file mentioned at [Azure Voting App](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-voting-app-redis/blob/master/kubernetes-manifests/azure-vote-all-in-one-redis.yaml)
I have a deployment file like:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: azure-vote-front
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
  minReadySeconds: 5 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: azure-vote-front
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: azure-vote-front
        image: microsoft/azure-vote-front:redis-v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 250m
          limits:
            cpu: 500m
        env:
        - name: REDIS
          value: "azure-vote-back"
```

I want to add an `imagePullSecret` to this file using a CLI and tried the following patch command which isn't working as expected. Can someone let me know what is the right way to add `impagePullSecret` to the deployment without modifying manually?

```
kubectl patch deployment azure-vote-front -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"imagePullSecret":[{"name":"mykey"}]}}}}'
```

**Error:**

```
Error from server: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type map[string]interface {}
```

Can you tell me what is wrong with the patch command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45502729/how-do-i-edit-a-resource-configuration-with-kubectl

Comment: It might be a duplicate in spirit, but this question is involving `patch`, which is an entirely different level of interactivity from `edit` and `apply`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it was merely an "example typo", or if that was quite literally your `patch` command, but the field is `imagePullSecrets`, plural (as the array contents might hint at), not `imagePullSecret` singular